# Create A Batch file to Run an EXE amd close it after the Exe is complete

Tags: window, dos

i need to write a batch file to run an executable. However this exe will not close by itself after running. It requires the user to hit enter to close the exe which is trigger from the batch file.

Now is that my exe and my batch file will be there until i manually hit enter to close the exe then the batch file will proceed and end this job

Is there a way to detect the completion of the exe and end the exe from the batch file itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the start command with a Windows .CMD file?

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS4\Photoshop.exe"
```

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/191149/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-silently

Comment: yup.... i have used. Cos the exe i run is a application console. Once they completed , it need to press enter to continue. If i nv manually press enter, the batch file will stuck there with the exe open

Comment: I would write a quick VB.NET Windows Console application that either A) sends a keystroke or B) Kills the process after a certain amount of time.  Sorry that I can't be of more help

Comment: Nvm thanks for help also. Maybe i will approach it in another direction